# Parsing data files for specific columns and specific rows using python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a data file that contains data in the following format. I would like to parse the data into 3 different files based on the id number and only get columns 3, 4 5 6 and 9. How do I do it in python!?
The data looks like the below example with each column representing the following quantities:

I only would like to retrieve data which has columns 3 4 5 6 and 9 into 3 seperate files based on the same ID (just the numbers which are colored by both yellow and blue in the pic below!)

```
density ID time x y z u v w dia
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried?  If you post what code you have so far, it will be easier to offer help.

Comment: Take a look at the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html); it should be able to read that data with ease.

Answer (score 1):

If every column is separated by a whitespace and you know that there won't be whitespaces in "cells", then you could do something very simple as:

```
f=open('/path/to/file')
for li in f.readlines():
    data = li.strip().split(' ')
    print data
```

`strip` will get rid of the `\n` at the end of every line ; here I split with `' '` but you could do it with anything, such as a tab `\t`.

`data[i]` will get you the value for column `i`.

To write files, juste use `open` with the `'w'` option and use the `write()` function.